# Toggle Function in jQuery Vector Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to implement toggle function in jQuery vector map,

My requirement is here: if user selected any region it should highlight with color.
 If user click same region it should go old state(without color or default state).

Can I achieve this using JS and jQuery or I need any other plugin help.

Any idea, suggestion and guidance highly appreciated. THANKS

### sample code:

```
<script src="Mobile Portal Management Tool (MPMT)_files/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'usa_en',
        enableZoom: true,
        showTooltip: true,
    //    selectedRegion: 'MO'
        onRegionClick: function(event, code, region)
        {
           /* var message = 'You selected "'
                + region 
                + '" which has the code: '
                + code.toUpperCase()
     //       alert(message);
            $('#location-selected').html(message); */



            var ul = $('#location-selected');
            var list = ul.children('li');
            var isInList = false;
            for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                if(list[i].innerHTML === region) {
                    isInList = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isInList)
                alert("User selected region already in the list")
            else
                var newli = $('<li></li>').html(region).appendTo(ul);       

            $('ul').children('li').on('dblclick',function()
            {
                //alert("Selected list item will be removed from the list...")
                $(this).remove();
            });
         }


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by assigning the property `colors` to the selected regions. For example to make california blue you can write something like this

```
    var highlight = {colors: {ca : '#0000ff'}}
```

To set the colors property from the clock callback you can call this

```
    onRegionClick: function(element, code, region) {
        $('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', highlight);
    }
```

And to toggle the colors you can add in a if switch that just checks if the element has the highlight color set. And this you can also use to append/remove the region to/from the list.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        highlight = {};
        $('#vmap').vectorMap({
            map: 'usa_en',
            enableZoom: true,
            showTooltip: true,
            color: '#f4f3f0',
            onRegionClick: function(element, code, region) {
                if(highlight[code]!=='#0000ff'){
                    highlight[code]='#0000ff';
                    $('<li id=\"li_'+code+'\"></li>').html(region).appendTo($('#location-selected'));
                } else {
                    highlight[code]='#f4f3f0';
                    $('#li_'+code).remove();
                }
                $('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', highlight);
            },
             onRegionOut: function(element, code, region){
                 $('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', highlight);
             },
        });
    });
```

I also put this on jsfiddle for a quick illustration:
[**http://jsfiddle.net/FxVzG/**](http://jsfiddle.net/FxVzG/)

For it to work properly you need to set the colors also in the `onRegionOut`.

Comment: Hi Martin Turjak,
Thanks for your response, the functionality part is working fine as expected but the color highlighting is not happening.

Comment: cool, I am glad it works for you =) Then you can accept my answer by checking it off under the vote arrows ... I am saying this cause you seem new to stackoverflow ... and you have not been really upvoting or accepting any answers for your other questions =)

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class to highlight then use JS or jQuery to toggle?

**CSS highlight class:**

```
.highlighted {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**jQuery toggle**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#text').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    });
});
```

Example taken from Codecademy: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHemN)

Comment: Thanks for you response.
I got it this example. But I don't know what element i am clicking because its jQuery Vector Map.. So I am bit confuse how to proceed...

Comment: Can you post us some sample code then? Better, put in in JSFiddle. People will be more willing to help you if you make it easier for them. :)

Comment: Yes heatly, I placed some sample code.. you can able to get it what I am looking...